# for a given no. find no. of possible ways to get that no. adding digits from a given set of no

Tags: c++

I am working on my school assignment that reads

> for a given no. find no. of possible ways to get that no. adding
>   digits from a given set of no.

i.e,

if I am given a set of No. `a =1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6` and another no `b=7` I need to find the no. of possible ways to get & adding a, b, c, d, e, f.
Repetition of digits is allowed.
Like in the above case I can get 7 in following ways:

- 4+3
- 5+2
- 4+2+1
- 6+1
- 1+1+1+1+1+1+1
- 2+2+2+1
- and more

How can I achieve the goal??Their are solutions for the problem in different languages but I don't know any lang except for C, C++;

Comment: I am just brute forcing. But, that is taking really long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find all subsets that sum to a particular value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value)

Comment: No, the solutions to the problem is in C#, Python, Java and I don't know any of these.

Comment: That C# answer doesn't use any C# features that don't have direct equivalents in C++.  Mentally replace `int[]` with `std::vector<int>` and you should be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

try out this:

```
#include < iostream>
#include < vector>

using namespace std;

 struct State {
    int v;
    const State *rest;
    void dump() const {
        if(rest) {
            cout << ' ' << v;
            rest->dump();
        } else {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    State() : v(0), rest(0) {}
    State(int _v, const State &_rest) : v(_v), rest(&_rest) {}
};

void ss(int *ip, int *end, int target, const State &state) 
{
    if(target < 0) return; // assuming we don't allow any negatives
    if(ip==end && target==0) {
        state.dump();
        return;
    }
    if(ip==end)
        return;
    { // without the first one
        ss(ip+1, end, target, state);
    }
    { // with the first one
        int first = *ip;
        ss(ip+1, end, target-first, State(first, state));
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 2,59,3,43,5,9,8,62,10,4 };
    int * start = &a[0];
    int * end = start + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    ss(start, end, 12, State());
}
```