# Algorithm- Find the number of subsets whose sum is in the given range

Tags: algorithm, subset

This is an interview question. I'm given an array of numbers (duplicates, negative numbers possible) and the lower and upper limit of a range. I need to find the number of subsets possible which will sum to a number within the range. I did look at the question which looks for a particular sum ([find all subsets that sum to a particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value)) but I don't think trying to do that for every number in the range is the most efficient thing to do.

Range can be from -10^7 to 10^7.

Comment: It seems like the answer you link to can be adapted. You've probably already given it a little thought, but you don't describe where you got stuck in your question, so it's hard to provide useful help other than just writing a solution.

Comment: It is clearly NP-hard. A dynamic programming approach is natural.

Comment: This problem is at least as hard as subset sum problem, but when the sum of weights is bounded I don't know if it remains np-hard or becomes tractable.

Answer (score 1):

The classic DP for subset sum can be modified to solve this problem, keeping a count instead of a boolean indicator for whether a solution with the given sum exists.

```
def subset_sum_count(lst, a, b):
    sum_count = collections.Counter({0: 1})
    for x in lst:
        for s, c in list(sum_count.items()):
            sum_count[s + x] += c
    return sum(c for (s, c) in sum_counts.items() if a <= s <= b)
```