# Split array of integers to as many as possible sub-arrays with same sum

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I'm looking for an algorithm that can split array of integers as many as possible sub arrays with sum of X. I tried to create arrays from hi to low, but at the end I have only left bunch of 2 and its impossible to create subsets with odd sum.

At the moment I'm stuck because I do not know what to look/google for?

eg.
Each element can be used once, so all subsets can exist at the same time.

i had an array = [7,6,4,7,8,3,3,7,8,9,4,3,2,6,6,4,2,6]
and want to split it in to subsets with sum of 12.

[7,5],[4,8],[9,3],[3,8],[7,3,2],[6,6],[4,2,6]

[7,4] and the surplus.

Comment: Can you give a small example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Added to the original post

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) or more specific the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

You can find the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value) or on [this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/how-to-get-the-subsets-from-an-array-that-are-equal-to-input/).

Comment: I'm looking to split that array, not just listing all possible variations of subsets.

Comment: by listing all variations you already split the array (the variations are the new splitted arrays)

Comment: Knapsack helped me, it's bin-packing problem what i was looking for. Original post is a bit misleading!