# SSP Algorithm minimal subset of length k

Tags: subset-sum, pari

Suppose S is a set with t elements modulo n. There are indeed, 2^t subsets of any length. Illustrate a PARI/GP program which finds the smallest subset U (in terms of length) of distinct elements such that the sum of all elements in U is 0 modulo n. It is easy to write a program which searches via brute force, but brute force is infeasible as t and n get larger, so would appreciate help writing a program which doesn't use brute force to solve this instance of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Approach:

```
def isSubsetSum(st, n, sm) :

    # The value of subset[i][j] will be
    # true if there is a subset of 
    # set[0..j-1] with sum equal to i
    subset=[[True] * (sm+1)] * (n+1)

    # If sum is 0, then answer is true
    for i in range(0, n+1) :
        subset[i][0] = True

    # If sum is not 0 and set is empty,
    # then answer is false
    for i in range(1, sm + 1) :
        subset[0][i] = False

    # Fill the subset table in botton 
    # up manner
    for i in range(1, n+1) :
        for j in range(1, sm+1) :
            if(j < st[i-1]) :
                subset[i][j] = subset[i-1][j]
            if (j >= st[i-1]) :
                subset[i][j] = subset[i-1][j] or subset[i - 1][j-st[i-1]]

    """uncomment this code to print table
    for i in range(0,n+1) :
        for j in range(0,sm+1) :
            print(subset[i][j],end="")
    print(" ")"""

    return subset[n][sm];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value) I don't know weather it seems to work.

```js
function getSummingItems(a,t){
  return a.reduce((h,n) => Object.keys(h)
                                 .reduceRight((m,k) => +k+n <= t ? (m[+k+n] = m[+k+n] ? m[+k+n].concat(m[k].map(sa => sa.concat(n)))
                                                                                      : m[k].map(sa => sa.concat(n)),m)
                                                                 :  m, h), {0:[[]]})[t];
}
var arr = Array(20).fill().map((_,i) => i+1), // [1,2,..,20]
    tgt = 42,
    res = [];

console.time("test");
res = getSummingItems(arr,tgt);
console.timeEnd("test");
console.log("found",res.length,"subsequences summing to",tgt);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```